# How to capture specific strings from a file and dump it to diff file in perl

Tags: string, perl, parsing

I have a log file which contains results of various test conditions. It looks like

```
Starting TestCon1
Msg1:Criteria
Result:pass
Msg2:Criteria
Result:fail

Starting TestCon2
Msg1:Criteria
Result:fail
Msg2:Criteria
Result:pass

Starting TestCon3
Msg1:Criteria
Result:pass
```

I want to create a subroutine which just picks out the "Msg which have failed along with The TestCon they belong to.This will get dumped to a summary file showing-->
The Msg which failed ,the result and the TestCon it belongs to

I have no clue where to start with ,Can anyone give me an idea where to start with

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**

Comment: Start by opening the file and reading it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read file, use regex and variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $testcon;
my $msg;
while (<STDIN>)
{
    if (/^Starting (.+)$/) { $testcon = $1 }
    elsif (/^Msg(\d+:\s*.+)$/) { $msg = $1 }
    elsif (/^Result:\s*fail$/) { print "$testcon\t$msg\n" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting-point: if you set `$/` (the line delimiter) to the empty string (`''` or `""`), then each call to `<>` will return one block separated by blank lines. So, you can write something like:

```
sub subroutine_for_user2486369 {
    open my $filehandle, '<', 'file_for_user2486369.txt'
        or die "Couldn't open file: $@";
    local $/ = '';
    while (<>) {
        # now $_ is one of your blocks
        ... # code to examine $_, see if it's what you want, and print
        ... # your result
    }
    close $filehandle;
}
```